# How to construct the pipeline for hls videos (AES encrypted or not) in Gstreamer

Tags: ios, video, encryption, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I'm new to gstreamer. I want to realize an iOS app to play hls videos by gstreamer. I use the version 1.6.2. I followed some tutorials on the internet so I got the following pipeline:

`souphttpsrc location=some_m3u8_url ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux name=mux  mux. ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink  mux. ! queue ! aacparse ! faad ! autoaudiosink`

I found some hls video urls to test but strangely, it partially worked.
Sometimes it plays the video during several seconds and then it stops and it gives: `Error received from element hlsdemux0: Internal data stream error.`
Sometimes it dose not play the video but just shows the first frame of this video.

I also tried `playbin` and `decodebin`, but they didn't work. Error message like:
`Buffering 4%`
`Buffering 8%`
`Error received from element hlsdemux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error`

This kind of error made me upset for weeks and I could not find any help. Further more, what I need is to also play the encrypted video, but I have no idea if this function is integrated or not.

Hope someone can help me or give me some suggestions. Thanks a lot!

PS: Dev environment: Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3.1 (ipad).

Comment: can you upgrade to 1.6.4? I think there were some bugfixes.. also you can play with buffer sizes and use bigger buffers, also you can use simpler pipeline with `uridecodebin uri=somelocation buffer-size=10000000 name=u u. ! autovideosink u. autoaudiosink` or something like that..

Comment: @otopolsky Thanks for your suggestion. I updated but nothing went better. It buffered until 98% and it stopped and stayed at the first frame. No matter how I change the buffer-size, I can never play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution several months ago and it worked perfectly. So I post it in case someone need.

`souphttpsrc name=src ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux name=u  u. ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink  u. ! queue ! aacparse ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink`

Of course you can use playbin or uridecodebin for those who have not many needs of customizing.